# Unknown provider: $locationProvider from ui.router.router

Tags: angularjs, location-provider

I am getting Unknown provider: $locationProvider from ui.router.router error while running the angular webpage .

Is this due to any dependency injection or something else . !!!

Please help

Comment: add some related code..most probably you are missing to add `$location` dependency somewhere inside your code..

Comment: Most useful would be adding your various `angular.module()` calls.